# How to Edit or Add a New Row in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, new-operator, row, addition

My jqGrid that does a great job of pulling data from my database, but I'm having trouble understanding how the Add New Row functionality works.

Right now, I'm able to edit inline data, but I'm not able to create a new row using the Modal Box.  I'm missing that extra logic that says, "If this is a new row, post this to the server side URL" instead of modifying existing data.  (Right now, hitting Submit only clears the form and reloads the grid data.)

The documentation states that Add New Row is:

```
jQuery("#editgrid").jqGrid('editGridRow',"new",{height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:false});
```

but I'm not sure how to use that correctly.  I've spent alot of time studying the Demos, but they seem to all use an external button to fire the new row command, rather than using the Modal Form, which I want to do.

My complete code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>jqGrid</title>  

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>My Grid Data</h2>
<table id="list" class="scroll"></table>
<div id="pager" class="scroll c1"></div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
var lastSelectedId;

jQuery('#list').jqGrid({
url:'grid.php',
datatype: 'json',
mtype: 'POST',
colNames:['ID','Name', 'Price', 'Promotion'],
colModel:[    
   {name:'product_id',index:'product_id', width:25,editable:false},     
   {name:'name',index:'name', width:50,editable:true, edittype:'text',editoptions:{size:30,maxlength:50}},
   {name:'price',index:'price', width:50, align:'right',formatter:'currency', editable:true},
   {name:'on_promotion',index:'on_promotion', width:50, formatter:'checkbox',editable:true, edittype:'checkbox'}],
rowNum:10,
rowList:[5,10,20,30],
pager: $('#pager'),
sortname: 'product_id',
viewrecords: true,
sortorder: "desc",
caption:"Database",
width:500,
height:150,  
onSelectRow: function(id){
if(id && id!==lastSelectedId){
  $('#list').restoreRow(lastSelectedId);
  $('#list').editRow(id,true,null,onSaveSuccess);
  lastSelectedId=id; }},
editurl:'grid.php?action=save'}) 

.jqGrid('navGrid','#pager', 
    {refreshicon: 'ui-icon-refresh',view:true},
    {height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:true}, 
    {height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:true}, 
    {reloadAfterSubmit:true})

.jqGrid('editGridRow',"new",{height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:false}); 

function onSaveSuccess(xhr) 
{response = xhr.responseText; if(response == 1) return true; return false;}

</script></body></html>
```

If it makes it easier, I'd be willing to scrap the inline editing functionality and do editing and posting via modal boxes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: paul - any chance of posting your new code. I have managed to edit an existing row but am unable to add new row. I have tried reading the demos but am getting totally confused Thanks

Comment: @Paul, could you pleae tell me how to add and edit rows? I am new to it :(

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't call `jqGrid('editGridRow',"new"...)` in most cases. Instead of that you should have the user click an **Add Record** button. Then a dialog will appear with all fields which have `editable=true` in colModel.

After they click the **Submit** button, `jqGrid` will POST data to the URL defined by `url` parameter or `editurl` parameter (if it exists). Because you use parameter `mtype='POST'` for the data filling, you have to define additional `editurl` parameter. You can overwrite POST HTTP code to PUT or any other which you like.

It is important to understand that the `id` for new records has an `_empty` value. The **Edit** dialog works in the same way as the **Add** dialog, but includes the `id` of the modified record. As an additional important parameter which will be sent to the server in the case of add new record is additional parameter `oper=add`.

For more information read section ***What is posted to the server*** on http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing.

I recommend that you also read about different parameters sent by `jqGrid` in the description of 
`prmNames` parameter on http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options

Comment: Oleg, thank you very much for the reply.  This is the best explanation I've seen anywhere.

Just to further clarify for anybody else reading this post: calling jqGrid('editGridRow',"new") in the way I did above fires up the modal form without the user requesting it.  Not what I intended.

Also, I didn't previously understand about the additional parameter being sent to the server side file for new records.

You need to use that extra parameter on the server side to determine the operation being requested by your grid.

Again, thanks.

Comment: Hello Paul. I am glad to hear, that I could help you. By the way, you can mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: In my case I can get Addi Record Dialog but can not edit fields even if I set fields editable