# jqGrid: POST data to server to fetch row data (filtering and searching)

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a form like this:

```
<form id='myForm'>
<input type='text' name='search' />
<input type='text' name='maxPrice' />
</form>
```

and table for my jqGrid:

```
<table id='myGrid'></table>
```

I need to POST (not GET) the data from `myForm` to my server method in order to fetch the row data and populate the grid. So far, I've not been able to get jqGrid to POST anything. I double-checked my data serialization and it is serializing my form data properly. Here is my jqGrid code:

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid({
    url: '/Products/Search") %>',
    postData: $("#myForm").serialize(),
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames: ['Product Name', 'Price', 'Weight'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'ProductName', index: 'ProductName', width: 100, align: 'left' },
        { name: 'Price', index: 'Price', width: 50, align: 'left' },
        { name: 'Weight', index: 'Weight', width: 50, align: 'left' }
    ],
    rowNum: 20,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    imgpath: gridimgpath,
    height: 'auto',
    width: '700',
    //pager: $('#pager'),
    sortname: 'ProductName',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption: "Products",
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
    headertitles: true,
    sortable: true,
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        root: function(obj) { return obj.Items; },
        page: function(obj) { return obj.CurrentPage; },
        total: function(obj) { return obj.TotalPages; },
        records: function(obj) { return obj.ItemCount; },
        id: "ProductId"
    }
});
```

Can you see what I'm doing wrong or should be doing differently?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your main error is the usage of the `postData` parameter in the form:

```
postData: $("#myForm").serialize()
```

This usage has two problems:

1. The value `$("#myForm").serialize()` overwrite all parameters of the POST requests instead of the adding additional parameters.
2. The value `$("#myForm").serialize()` will be calculated **only once** during the grid initialization time. So you will send always `search=""` and `maxPrice=""` to the server.

I suggest you to to replace the form with named edit fields to

```
<fieldset>
<input type='text' id='search' />
<input type='text' id='maxPrice' />
<button type='button' id='startSearch'>Search</button>
</fieldset>
```

define `postData` parameter as object with methods:

```
postData: {
    search: function() { return $("#search").val(); },
    maxPrice: function() { return $("#maxPrice").val(); },
},
```

and add `onclick` event handler to the "Search" button (see above HTML fragment)

```
$("#startSearch").click(function() {
    $("#myGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");
});
```

Moreover you write nothing about the server technology which you use. It can be some additional modification is required to be able to read parameters on the server side (for example `serializeRowData: function (data) {return JSON.stringify(data);}` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917102/jqgrid-add-row-and-send-data-to-webservice-for-insert/3918615#3918615) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912008/jqgrid-does-not-populate-with-data/3914796#3914796)). I recommend you also to read another old answer: [How to filter the jqGrid data NOT using the built in search/filter box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819).

Some other small errors like `'/Products/Search") %>'` instead of '/Products/Search' or the usage of deprecated parameter `imgpath` (see [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:upgrade_from_3.4.x_to_3.5#options)) are less important. The default column options like `align: 'left'` should be better removed.

Consider also to use searching in the grid. For example [advance searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching)

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
                    {add:false,edit:false,del:false,search:true,refresh:true},
                    {},{},{},{multipleSearch:true});
```

and also [toolbar searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching):

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar',
                    {stringResult:true,searchOnEnter:true,defaultSearch:"cn"});
```

it can probably replace the searching form which you use.

Comment: @Byron Sommardahl: you wrote no comment on my answer since a week. Do you read my answer? Could it help you? Is your problem already solved?

Comment: Yet another awesome answer from @Oleg.

Comment: @AJ.: I'm glad that the old answer is still helpful.

Comment: I think he can move $("#myForm").serialize() into a function like getFormDataToPost() and assign that function to postData:getFormDataToPost(). Will it work?

Comment: Been tearing my hair out trying to figure this one out- thanks for your answer. I feel like simply doing postData: $('#form').serialize() *should* work though. Why does it override all POST parameters? What params are we talking about?

Comment: @IcedDante it is wrong because it is evaluated too soon, before the form is even filled in.  instead you could do `$("#myGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam", "postData", $('#form').serialize())` later, after the form submit button is pressed, for example