# jqGrid Delete a Row

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I have created my grid and would like to use default behaviour of the grid to delete a row.

This is my grid setup code:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#grid_pager',
    { add: true, addtitle: 'Add Customer', 
      edit: true, edittitle: 'Edit Customer',
      del: true, deltitle: 'Delete Customer', 
      refresh: true, refreshtitle: 'Refresh data',
      search: true, searchtitle: 'Advanced search filters', 
      addfunc: addReferent, editfunc: editReferent
    },
    {}, // default settings for edit
    {}, // default settings for add
    { // define settings for Delete 
        mtype: "post", 
        reloadAfterSubmit: true,
        url: wsBaseUrl + 'CustomerService.asmx/DeleteCustomer',
        resize: false,
        serializeDelData: function(postdata) {
            return JSON.stringify({ customerID: postdata.id });
        }
    },
    { // define settings for search
        closeOnEscape: true, multipleSearch: true, closeAfterSearch: true 
    }, 
    {}
);
```

and this is the web service method defined on the server

```
[WebMethod]
public OperationResult Deletecustomer(string customerID)
{
}
```

but unfortunately when I click the delete button and click ok on the confirm window I get an error saying 404. as in the following picture

[image: Error screenshot]

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I have added the following code to my jqGrid Initialization

```
// Set defaults value for jqGrid
$.jgrid.defaults = $.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
    mtype: 'post',
    datatype: 'json',
    jsonReader: {
        root: "d.Rows",
        page: "d.Page",
        total: "d.Total",
        records: "d.Records",
        repeatitems: false,
        userdata: "d.UserData",
        id: "Id"
    },
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
    serializeGridData: function (postData) {
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    },
    ajaxDelOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
    serializeDelData: function (postData) {
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    },
    loadui: "block",
    multiboxonly: true,
    rowNum: 25,
    rowList: [25, 50, 100],
    altRows: true,
    altclass: 'ui-priority-secondary',
    autoencode: true,
    autowidth: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    rownumWidth: 30,
    gridview: true,
    hoverrows: true,
    viewrecords: true
});
```

but I still get the same error...

Comment: You should additionally verify the URL which you use because HTTP code 404 is "Not Found" in the most cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you should just use `JSON.stringify` (from [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)) inside of `serializeDelData`. You don't posted the prototype of your web method `DeleteCustomer` which you need to delete, but probably your problem could be fixed with the following code:

```
serializeDelData: function(postdata) {
    return JSON.stringify({customerID: postdata.id});
}
```

One more common problem in case of the usage of ASMX services. It can be need to define all parameters of the web method called (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917102/jqgrid-add-row-and-send-data-to-webservice-for-insert/3918615#3918615) an example).

The usage of `ajaxDelOptions: { contentType: "application/json" }` parameter is also required mostly.

It can be helpful to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to capture and analyse the HTTP traffic.

Comment: @Oleg: thanks for your answer. I was just editing my question while you were answering to it and adding all the things you said. Where should I add the ajaxDelOptions parameter?

Comment: @Lorenzo: You can use `ajaxDelOptions: { contentType: "application/json" }` either as an additional option of "Del" (on the same level as `reloadAfterSubmit: true`) or to extend `$.jgrid.del` and not `$.jgrid.defaults` (see [the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917102/jqgrid-add-row-and-send-data-to-webservice-for-insert/3918615#3918615) which I previously posted). I find very strange the error code 404 which you has. So I recommend you to use Fiddler/Firebug to see what be send, use everywhere `DeleteCustomer` or `Deletecustomer` and examine `web.config`

Comment: @Oleg: sometimes I read too fast... and so I did not realize the difference between `$.jgrid.del` and `$.jgrid.defaults`. Now everything works. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Oleg: sorry to be back on the argument. I just would like to ask you if there's a way to catch the result of the delete call. My `DeleteCustomer` method return back a json object that contains details on the operation. How can I retrieve that result with this setup? Thanks again

Comment: @Lorenzo: If you want just read additional information returned by your `DeleteCustomer` method you can use it inside of `afterSubmit` event handler defined of the same level as other "Del" parameter or in the `$.jgrid.del`. The `afterSubmit` has two parameters: `data` as text returned by the server (you should call `jQuery.parseJSON` manually) and the same `postdata` which received by `serializeDelData`.

Comment: @Oleg: Great!!! Anyway when using `afterSubmit` the dialog that ask for `Are you sure to delete?` does not hide automatically anymore. Should I call any function to hide it?

Comment: @Lorenzo: What you return from the `afterSubmit`? It should be array like `[true,'']` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events2)).

Comment: @Oleg: Perfect! You are an invaluable help on the jqGrid :) Thanks!