# How to delete a jqgrid row without reloading the entire grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have a webpage with multiple jqgrids each with inline editing enabled, "action" column (edit icons) enabled and pager disabled. I need to handle the delete event for each row so that I can process the delete without reloading server-side data. I've looked at the approach mentioned in [jqGrid Delete a Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122392/jqgrid-delete-a-row) and it's very helpful except I have two questions that are stumping me -

1. Are there more details around the `rp_ge` parameter in the `delOptions.onClickSubmit` event?
   My column has the delOptions set as this -

`delOptions: {onclickSubmit: function(rp_ge, rowid) {return onRowDelete(rp_ge,rowid);}},processing:true }},`

Is there a way to get the grid id from within that event? I'd like to have a generic function that I can use to handle delete events from all the grids on the page. The `rp_ge` parameter has a `gbox` which sometimes contains the grid id appended? But I have no idea what it is since i'm not able to figure out when it's populated, when it's not.

```
function onRowDelete(rp_ge, rowid) {
 //hardcoded grid id.. don't like it.
 var gridid = '#Grid_X';
 //what is this gbox?? can i get grid id predictable from it?
 //var gridid = rp_ge.gbox.replace("#gbox_", "");
 var grid = $('#Grid_X');
 rp_ge.processing = true;
 var result = grid.delRowData(rowid);
 if (result) {
    $("#delmod" + grid[0].id).hide();
 }
 return true;
}
```

2. In the [jqGrid Delete a Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122392/jqgrid-delete-a-row) approach, the code `$("#delmod"+grid[0].id).hide();` is hiding the popup delete confirmation dialog manually. What I noticed is that when the dialog pops-up, jqgrid de-emphasizes the background page (makes it light greyish). But after the popup is manually closed (hidden actually?), the background remains de-emphasized. So it looks like the page doesn't have focus (or even disabled). Any way this can be fixed? This can also be seen on the [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ActionButtons.htm) that [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg) wrote.

Any help would be appreciated. 
(PS - I would've commented on the same post but I don't have enough points to comment on someone else's answer yet.)

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your second point.
Several examples by [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg) such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796480/how-to-delete-rows-with-local-data-in-jqgrid) one have the following modification.

```
 $("#delmod" + grid[0].id).hide();
```

is replaced with

```
$.jgrid.hideModal(
    "#delmod"+grid_id, 
    {gb:"#gbox_"+grid_id,jqm:rp_ge.jqModal,onClose:rp_ge.onClose}
);
```

This will return focus after the delete operation.